# How to a keep a complex expression out of my HTML in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm working on a project where users will fill out a few HTML `<input>`s in a `<form>` in order to generate some preview output right below the form. Here is a simplified example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/64Okgv4Ncb5yL7jOM6Xt?p=preview

I don't want to show the preview output until there's a value in every field. One way to accomplish that (as used in the Plunker above) is via the [`ngShow` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow):

```
<div class="container-fluid output" ng-show="event.name && event.date && event.category && event.location">
```

That's not too crazy, but here I've greatly simplified the actual logic that I need to implement. There are multiple special cases that will determine whether to display the preview. If I stick with this approach, the expression will become a long, tangled mess of a JavaScript conditional right in my HTML.

The other approach that I'm aware of is to use `$watchCollection()` (I'll call it `$watch` for simplicity's sake). Here's a Plunker where I've set up the equivalent with `$watch`:

http://plnkr.co/edit/UPToOlQCZddJ2a1Ye1cq?p=preview

It works just the same, but I'm concerned that this isn't the most efficient or effective solution, in which case I don't want to make a habit of it. My understanding is that `$watch`es are generally costly, and should be using sparingly.

That leads to my questions:

1. Is there a better approach to this than using `$watch`?
2. If not, can the `$watch` I'm using be modified to improve performance?
3. Am I too cautious about using `$watch` here? Is using `ngShow` with an expression really just doing the same thing behind the scenes?

Thanks for any feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use watch but there is one another simple solution for that for same by using a scope function where you can put your logic to show preview or not.

```
$scope.event = {};

$scope.showPreview = function() {
    if (!$scope.event) {    // if none is filled
        return false;
    }

    if (!$scope.event.name || !$scope.event.date || !!$scope.event.category || !$scope.event.location) {
        return false;
    }

    if (/* your custom or special logic */) {
        // if satisfies then return true else return false
    }
    return true;
};
```

Now you can simply write in your HTML like:

```
<div class="container-fluid output" ng-show="showPreview()"></div>
```

Angular will automatically evaluate the expression whenever output from `showPreview` method returns a different value and will show or hide the dialog accordingly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Aha! That's clean, simple, and respects separation of concerns. I know about scope functions and was sure there had to be a better way than my  expression approach, but I'm too new to AngularJS to have recognized the pattern. This was a light bulb moment, though. Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Any expression in `ng-show` is implemented as a watch, so you won't be saving a lot.

$watch is expensive in the sense that it will be executed after every keystroke.  If you have a hundred of them, the user will notice the slow-down.  One isn't going to matter.

Comment: Thanks! That's helpful to know that it's going to be a watch behind the scenes anyway. I appreciate your input.